# refresh button is killing the controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngroute

I have a problem between my template and controller. When i hit the refresh button on the web browser my controller is getting destroyed and not getting created again. So view doesnt function. Is there any way to avoid this error ?

UPDATE :
It was an other service which caused ctrl not the work. I solved the problem but still i couldnt figure out how to manipulate the URL when a person presses refresh in the browser..

Comment: show ur controller and also say what is the error u r observing on console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            // For unmatched routes
            $urlRouterProvider
                .when('', '/home')
                .otherwise('/errorPage');

            // Application routes
            $stateProvider
                .state('someState', {
                    url: '/somePage',
                    controller: 'SomeCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'any.html',
                })
                .state('otherOne', {
                    url: '/otherPage',
                    templateUrl: 'other.html',
                })
    }
```

And to shitch between states use `<a ui-sref="someState">cLick Me</a>`

Comment: TS is not using angular ui-router